# Should I use <picture> and <source> with next/image?

Tags: html, image, next.js

I used next/image before and worked great, but never knew how the optimization worked.
Now I am learning on optimizing images in Html5 and Css3 with the usage of `<picture>` and `<source>`. I am a bit confused if I could combine these with next/image or if next image itself takes care loading images depending on the device width.

Comment: Next.js's Image component has a prop called layout, and setting this to ```layout="responsive"``` will scale the image by the viewport. see https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image

Comment: Yes, but my confusion comes in when I can only see in the documentation the especification regarding the width for responsiveness, does that afect also the size of the downloading for the client? or just the adjusting of width for responsiveness?

Comment: Next strongly favors you leaving the plumbing part of the optimization up to them. I have tried overriding their stuff in Webpack and endured a lot of pain. Just leave the settings alone.

Comment: @DiegoCortés _"does that afect also the size of the downloading for the client? or just the adjusting of width for responsiveness?"_ Next.js image optimization will also optimize the size of the image for better performance. See [Image Component and Image Optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization).